# Settlers 3 on Linux: Wine, CD change recognition and piracy protection

Tags: wine, the-settlers-3

I installed The Settlers 3 on my Linux Mint PC, using Wine to run it. Since it is the original version with 2 CDs - CD2 for campaign and CD1 for everything else, I get the following problem:

Sometimes the game asks me to insert CD1 / CD2 (e.g. when CD1 is inside and I want to start a campaign). I can do that and then click OK, but the game does not recognize the change. It only recognizes the CD that I inserted before starting the game.

So currently I cannot play the campaign: To start scenario N+1, one has to finish scenario N and then end the game. Since I want to play occasionally (sleep every now and then), this means that I make a savegame of a won scenario N. For loading a savegame I need CD1, but when I end the game to get to scenario N+1, the game asks for CD2.

I tried to get around this issue by creating ISO files of the two CDs using command line tool dd. Since dd does not work for audio CDs and the CDs are both data and audio CDs, I get an error message "Input/output error" when creating the ISOs.  I can still mount both ISOs and that way load games (CD1) and start the next campaing scenario (CD2) - but when using the ISOs, the game recognizes piracy (which shows in the game as iron smelters producing pigs instead of iron bars)...

What can I do?
I only have one CD drive, so I either need a way to make Wine/Settlers3 recognize the CD change or get the ISOs working without making the game think that I am pirating.

Any hints?